# Accessing PowerPoint UWP Local App Data virtualized folder location from Win32 app

Tags: delphi, uwp, com, powerpoint, desktop-bridge

I have an application that accesses PowerPoint using COM in order to export thumbnails from a PowerPoint file. After the export, the thumbnails will be displayed. I'm exporting the thumbnails to the local appdata folder of my application, in order to cache the exported thumbnails. Here's a simplified example:

```
uses
  MSPPT2000, Office2000, PngImage;

var
  FPP: TPowerPointApplication;
  FPres:  TPowerPointPresentation;
  FileName, ExportFolder: string;
begin
  FileName := Edit1.Text;

  FPP := TPowerPointApplication.Create(nil);
  FPP.Connect;
  FPres := TPowerPointPresentation.Create(nil);
  FPres.ConnectTo(FPP.Presentations.Open(FileName, msoTrue, msoTrue, msoFalse));

  ExportFolder := GetFolder_LocalAppData + 'PowerPointExportTest';      // 'C:\Users\Testuser\AppData\Local\PowerPointExportTest'
  ForceDirectories(ExportFolder);

  FPres.Slides.Item(1).Export(ExportFolder + '\Page1.png', 'PNG', 200, 100);

  FPres.Free;
  FPP.Free;

  Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExportFolder + '\Page1.png');
end;
```

This code has worked fine for years, but now a user has installed PowerPoint 365 from the Microsoft Store. The `Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile` call fails with an `EFOpenError` because the thumbnail does not exist.

It's not that the thumb doesn't exist, but it is written to a different folder than I had requested:
`C:\Users\Testuser\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local\PowerPointExportTest\Page1.png`.

It looks like PowerPoint now has become an UWP application, and the folders are virtualized using the desktop-bridge.

I could now hard code this path, but that doesn't feel right. What is the official way to access the exported thumb file using a Win32 application?

```
  try
    Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(ExportFolder + '\Page1.png');
  except
    on E: EFOpenError do
    begin
      ShowMessage('File not found in the expected place, trying hard coded alternative path');
      Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(GetFolder_LocalAppData + 'Packages\Microsoft.Office.Desktop_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local\PowerPointExportTest\Page1.png');
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Since this is user generated content shouldn't that be in the documents folder which is accessible by all (UWP) apps? The AppData folder should be for storing application data (by MS in this case) and is meant to be sandboxed in UWP context. Plus, the last part of the folder name will differ across users and change with updates.

Comment: The exported thumbnail images are used to display the thumbnails of the PowerPoint pages in my application. I'd hate to clutter up the user documents folder with them.

Comment: You clean up the generated files later anyway, do you? What about an random temp directory? I don't get why it had to be AppData\Local\ in the first place.

Comment: The temporary folder is also within the local appdata folder. So it would have the same issue. I delete the thumbnails when they were not accessed for 8 days, so it might take a while until they are cleaned up. If there is no way to access the sandboxed folder, then I'll have to export to the user documents folder and then move them to my local appdata folder.

Comment: Looking at the spec here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/ and especially here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions it seems to me that you cannot gain access to AppData folder of another App so using the Documents folder as a temporary cache for you files may be your only option

Comment: Does `GetTempPath()` give you the real `%TEMP%` location that's visible to all?